# VSS Hardware Provider Get_TargetLuns copy serial number in m_rgbIdentifier

Tags: c++, com, backup, storage, volume-shadow-service

In Get_Targetluns, i cloned the ZFS volume and shared with targetGroups and get the serial number of the disk

> My serial number is in the form of 69 71 6e 2e 32 30 31 30 2d 30 38 2e
>   6f 72 67 2e

In BSTR string i get the serial number in form of 69716e2e323031302d30382e6f72672e

Now i want to copy this BSTR value to the

> rgDestinationLuns[0]->m_deviceIdDescriptor[0]->m_rgIdentifiers[0]->m_rgbIdentifier

When i do the mem copy and copy the string its not working, always getting Missing Disk Error

Even in the VSS trace am not getting the expected value in the 
Am getting some thing like this

> [ 1:34:09.466 P:03C0 T:0878 CORHWUTC(2805)   HWDIAG] * PARAM OUT:
>   m_rgbIdentifier:
>
> [ 1:34:09.466 P:03C0 T:0878 CORHWUTC(2971)   HWDIAG]
>   * PARAM OUT:                    30 31 34 30  42 30 41 41   30 30 35 35  37 36 30 32    0140B0AA00557602

How to assign the BSTR value to the m_rgbIdentifier ?

Comment: Did you sort this out? I have a different but related question. BTW, the hexadecimal digits spell out "iqn:2010-08:org:". I wonder if this is really the disk serial number, as it looks like an IQN (partial?) string. If it isn't really the serial number it may explain your problem. The last error message decodes to 0140B0AA00557602, which does look like it could be a serial number (right number of digits, no alpha or special chars).